# Get the sum of a field using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I started using Laravel and i loved this framework, right now i started working on a small project and i would like to know how can i use **SUM** to get the total of variant that i have in a table called **variants**, i would like to sum **stock** field,

stock field exist in variants table;

how can i use sum With the eloquent

this is my code

```
$products = Product::with(['category', 'brand', 'supplier'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

my model variant function

```
public function variant(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Variant', 'product_id','id');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to for calling has-many sum with [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

### Add accessor:

In product model:

```php
protected $appends = ['stock_sum'];

public function getStockSumAttribute() {
    return $this->variants()->sum('stock');
}
```

So you can call it by product:

```php
$products = Product::with(['category', 'brand', 'supplier'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(15);
$products->first()->stock_sum;
```

Comment: You can improve the performance by using `$this->variants()->sum('stock')`. It will be a lot faster when the `variants` relationship is not eager loaded and is not needed.

Comment: @EliasSoares u'r right, thx for advice, I just sum on collection. use `variants()->sum` sum in db. I have updated.

Comment: @TsaiKoga i get stock_sum: 0 since i have two rows each one contain number 10
i have updated my question 
check my variant function

Comment: @TsaiKoga its okey thank you just i would like to understand getStockSumAttribute function how and where you have call it

Comment: @RicardoAbel it is a virtual attribute, if you defined this getter method, you have this attribute, you can call it by each product object.

Comment: @RicardoAbel u'r welcome, if it helps, plz accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have any filters/conditions on which you sum? If not it could be as easy as:

```
$sum = Variant::sum('stock');
```

How is the `variants` table related to the `products` table?

Comment: using product_id field

Comment: how can i do it with my eloquent ; Product::with(['category', 'brand', 'supplier'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(15);

Comment: Do you want the sum of stock for ALL related products, or just products on the page that has been retrieved?